# Mysqli sentenças preparadas

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

Olá, estou com um problema, gostaria de saber a respeito de sentenças preparadas, tenho esse código:

```
$query_email = ("SELECT email FROM usuarios_ WHERE email = ?");

$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
if (mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $query_email)) {     
   mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $email);
   mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
   mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $resultado);
   mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);

   echo $resultado;

   mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);        
}
```

Até aqui tudo bem, minha dúvida é, como saber se teve resultado ou não, pois como é um sistema de login tenho que passar o retorno para o usuário se o e-mail existe ou não.

Comment: Seu código parece certo, qual é o problema? ou você quer o número de linhas retornadas?

Comment: Ray,, precisava saber se a consulta teve registros ou não, ou seja se ela encontrou o e-mail fornecido pelo usuário.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se é um sistema de login, tem um problemas - Não sei se esse é todo seu código, mas se for, você deve procurar também pela senha, nunca apenas por e-mail. Se seu objetivo é apenas informar ao usuário se o e-mail existe ou não (durante processo de login), digo que isso é uma péssima ideia. Você esta entregando a um atacante metade das informações que ele precisa para invadir o seu sistema.

[mysqli_stmt_fetch](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php) retorna verdadeiro/falso caso um registro seja encontrado, pode usar isso para realizar uma checagem e saber se existe ou não o e-mail em seu banco de dados. Acho que é isso que você deseja.

Para recuperar o valor persistido em seu banco, e armazenar em variáveis, use o [mysqli_stmt_bind_result](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php). Existem alguns exemplos na documentação da função sobre como utilizá-la.

Comment: Renato, sim...tem mais código..aproveitando sua experiência, pois eu estou meio que começando com sentenças preparadas e agora estou fazendo um login com salt, e pelo que percebi login com salt aleátorio não tem como fazer a verificação login e senha em uma única linha de sql, a forma que encontrei foi essa...busca o e-mail...se encontrar verifica a senha, há unica forma é essa mesmo?

Comment: @DungaCardoso Você precisa armazenar o salt junto com o e-mail e a senha criptografada, ou seja, três campos ao invés de dois. O login pode ser feito de uma unica vez (unico select), selecionando da tabela com os três campos, concatenando o salt e realizando a checagem do hash. outras informações aqui http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1645161/salt-generation-and-open-source-software/1645190#1645190

Comment: Minha dificuldade é essa...pq fiz dessa forma no banco: |email | senha + salt criptografado | salt....então pra fazer um select eu pego o email...se existir...eu pego a senha digitada...criptografo, concateno mais o salt e criptografo novamente, o resultado eu comparo com a senha do banco..

Comment: A senha vc criptografa uma vez, se o cara digitar renato@email.com e a senha 123456 tu da um select email, salt, senha from users where email = email_enviado se existir esse email ele retorna um dado né... ai tu pega o salt que recebeu do select e concatena direto com a senha (123456abcdef) ai sim criptografa, e verifica se bate. PHP tem várias funções para cuidar de senhas em suas versões mais novas http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/faq.passwords.php

Comment: Exatamente isso...minha dificuldade estava em quando eu fazia o select pedindo mais de um campo tipo, select email, senha, estava dando erro..porem descobri que a cada campo do select precisa de uma variavél no bind para receber o valor...dessa forma acredito que consigo fazer tudo em um select apenas... Obrigado..

Comment: Olha o resultado: SELECT email, senha, hash FROM usuarios_ WHERE email = ? and senha = md5(concat(md5(?), hash)) @Renato Tavares

Comment: Não use MD5. Tente algo novo http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.password.php MD5 é fria https://www.bentasker.co.uk/blog/security/201-why-you-should-be-asking-how-your-passwords-are-stored